# Stripes annotation @UrlBinding is not working correctly. 302 status code

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-302, stripes, urlbinding

I am having troubles with a stripes action beans.

Introducing first http://localhost:9080/profesionales-sanitarios-war/medicos/publico/accesoInterno on the browser causes a 302 status code and redirects to AccesoActionBean

The second time I introduce http://localhost:9080/profesionales-sanitarios-war/medicos/publico/accesoInterno on the browser, it returns a 200 status code and works fine going to AccesoInternoActionBean.

It happens both localhost and server (development, preproduction and production).

AccesoActionBean.java:

```
@UrlBinding( "/medicos/publico/acceso" + "/{tipoAcceso}/{destino}" )
public class AccesoActionBean extends MedicosBaseActionBean {

[...]

    @DontValidate
    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution init() {
        setSessionField( SESION_CONTADOR_ACCESOS, contadorAccesos );
        if( tipoAcceso != null && "popup".equalsIgnoreCase( tipoAcceso ) ) {
            return new ForwardResolution( "/WEB-INF/pages/acceso/loginForm.jsp" );

        } else {
            return new ForwardResolution( NavegacionConst.JSP_ACCESO );
        }
    }

[...]

}
```

AccesoInternoActionBean.java:

```
@UrlBinding( "/medicos/publico/accesoInterno" )
public class AccesoInternoActionBean extends MedicosBaseActionBean {

[...]

    @DontValidate
    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution init() {
        setSessionField( SESION_CONTADOR, contadorAccesos );
        return new ForwardResolution( NavegacionConst.JSP_ACCESO_INTERNO );
    }

[...]

}
```

ActionBeans seems to be coded correctly, they are similar to others that redirect to right action bean from the first time. I've searched, I've debugged, but I couldn't find the answer. I think that problem could come from some configuration file like this web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
                               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>${project.build.finalName}</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>es.sanitas.medicos.stripes.listeners.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:es/sanitas/medicos/applicationContext-profesionales.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>oracle.adf.jsp.provider.5</param-name>
        <param-value>oracle.stellent.wcm.javaee.shared.jsp.IdcJspProvider</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Url del Servidor de Contenidos</description>
        <param-name>manageSite</param-name>
        <param-value>http://caliban01:8888/</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <display-name>Stripes Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Extension.Packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                es.sanitas.stripes.integrations.spring,
                net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring,
                es.sanitas.stripes.i18n
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                es.sanitas.medicos.stripes.actionbeans,
                es.sanitas.medicos.blua.stripes.actionbeans,
                es.sanitas.stripes.actionbeans.captcha,
                es.sanitas.medicopersonalprofesionales.stripes
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ExceptionHandler.Class</param-name>
            <param-value>es.sanitas.medicos.stripes.handlers.MedicosExceptionHandler</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Interceptor.Classes</param-name>
            <param-value>
                es.sanitas.medicos.stripes.interceptors.IsLoggedInterceptor,
                es.sanitas.stripes.interceptors.AuditBaseInterceptor
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>LocalePicker.Locales</param-name>
            <param-value>es_ES:UTF-8,ca_ES:UTF-8,en:UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>

           <init-param>
            <param-name>ResourceBundles.BaseNames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                es.sanitas.medicos.stripesErrors,
                es.sanitas.medicos.stripesMessages
            </param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/captcha/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/medicos/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/medicopersonalprofesionales/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/startProfesionalesSanitarios.jspx</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
        </jsp-property-group>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
        </jsp-property-group>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
            <is-xml>true</is-xml>
        </jsp-property-group>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.tagx</url-pattern>
            <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/medicos/error</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/medicos/inicio</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

I have searching for solutions, but I couldn't find any

I want to apologize if my writing is not entirely correct, because my native language is not English.

Comment: According to the @UrlBinding documentation, this is the correct parameter syntax: "Parameters may be embedded in the URL by placing the parameter name inside braces ({}). For example, @UrlBinding("/foo/{bar}/{baz}")} maps the action to "/foo" and indicates that the "bar" and "baz" parameters may be embedded in the URL. In this case, the URL /foo/abc/123 would invoke the action with bar set to "abc" and baz set to "123". The literal strings between parameters can be any string."

Comment: Excuse me, the problem is that when I type in a browser the URL  **.../medicos/publico/accesoInterno** once, the application returns a **302 status** and redirects to **.../medicos/publico/acceso**. If I retype **.../medicos/publico/accesoInterno** it returns a **200 status** and the correct page in **.../medicos/publico/accesoInterno**. I've just tested without the slash and the application involves in the same way.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were using both actionbeans together. I thought the second one was an alternative for the first. What exactly is in the JSP_ACCESO_INTERNO variable?

Comment: In NavegacionConst.java class: public static final String **JSP_ACCESO_INTERNO** = "/WEB-INF/pages/acceso/accesoInterno.jsp"; public static final String **JSP_ACCESO** = "/WEB-INF/pages/acceso/acceso.jsp"; Thank you very much for your comments and help.

Comment: OK, so the second ActionBean redirects to the first only once. I assume there is no redirection in the jsp files. There is no redirecting in the ActionBeans either. Hm... but there are some interceptor classes at work (`web.xml`) that may be responsible for redirection based on some variable initialization perhaps? You could try disabling them and see what happens.  [removed some no longer relevant comments]

Answer (score 0):

> OK, so the second ActionBean redirects to the first only once. I
>   assume there is no redirection in the jsp files. There is no
>   redirecting in the ActionBeans either. Hm... but there are some
>   interceptor classes at work (web.xml) that may be responsible for
>   redirection based on some variable initialization perhaps? You could
>   try disabling them and see what happens. [removed some no longer
>   relevant comments]

You're right "acdhirr" I've finally found the problem as your last response. In the web.xml I've commented both interceptor classes:

```
<!-- <init-param>
    <param-name>Interceptor.Classes</param-name>
    <param-value>
        es.sanitas.medicos.stripes.interceptors.IsLoggedInterceptor,
        es.sanitas.stripes.interceptors.AuditBaseInterceptor
    </param-value>
</init-param> -->
```

---

Now I've got to investigate with the team architects to found out alternative classes if them are really required or keep them commented.

Once, thank you very much for all your support and help.

Comment: That's cool. Happy to help and good luck with further investigations! (BTW considering the interceptor name I guess you'll want to keep at least some mechanism to ensure users are logged in!)